# Наобум

Tags: этимология

Я снова с этимологией. Интересует слово "наобум". А что такое, собственно, "обум"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово  "наобум" в современном языке обозначает  "наудачу", "наугад" или "не подумав"
Было в языке и слово "обум", судя по словарям, сохраняющееся в диалектах .

У Даля:   *Обум нареч. зря, очертя голову, наудачу, более говорят наобум.*

Т.е. получается, что наречие "наобум" образовано от другого наречия "обум" приставочным способом. В большинстве значений слова синонимичны. Только в современном "наобум", по-моему, значения "зря" нет. Наобум- не обязательно зря, можно пойти наобум, а толк будет.

Comment: Возможно, его и в "обум" нет. В подобных вопросах Далю верить на слово нельзя, надо смотреть независимые источники. Что-то мне подсказывает, что здесь тот самый случай.

Comment: В других словарях тоже есть. Но, возможно, тоже от Даля.

Answer (score 3):

Лев Успенский в Этимологическом словаре школьника пишет:
 Легко обнаружить три составляющих элемента: "на-" и "об-" -
две приставки и корень "-ум-". Все вместе значит "действуя в обход ума,
не ожидая совета разума": "об" имеет тут значение "до", "помимо".
Мне кажется такое объяснение верным, тем более, что оно не отменяет Даля, кот. приводит несколько значений в диалектах глагола "обумить", от которого и образовалось наречие:
ОБУМИТЬ кого, образумить, надоумить; дать опомниться; —ся, обуметь, поумнеть, надоумиться, образуметь, опомниться. || олон. выжить из ума, одуреть, оглупеть, стать забывчивым, беспамятным. || вологодск. изумиться, удивиться, опешать, стать втупик. Как крикнет он на меня, так я и обумела! || Обумиться, пск. твер. обмануться, ошибиться. Обум нареч. зря, очертя голову, наудачу, более говорят наобум. || Арх. перм. напрасно, тщетно, без пользы, попусту. Я обум сходил, не застал его. Обумок м. полудурье. Говорят наобум (наглум), а ты бери на умалит.